# addition of a kernel and a function

Tags: machine-learning, self-study, mathematical-statistics, svm, kernel-trick

I have this problem.

[image]

My approach would be to take a Kernel matrix of $ \ k(x,y) $ as it is positive semidefinitive. And if I am able to make $ \ k'(x,y) $ a kernel matrix, then I can prove that it is a kernel. But I don't understand how can I use this in the proof $ \ δ(x, y) $

Comment: do you know if $\delta$ by itself is a kernel or not? If we're only talking about matrices, note that $x^T(A+B)x = x^T A x + x^T B x$. Do you see how to use this?

Comment: If δ would've been a kernel, I could've solved that. In fact I already solved that. But, if it is a function as mentioned in the question, how can I do then?

Comment: a kernel is just a function too, except with the extra condition that for any finite set of points $\{x_i\}$ the matrix $K$ with $K_{ij} = k(x_i, x_j)$ is PSD. What's the corresponding matrix look like for $\delta$?

Comment: According to the given condition, I think it is an identity matrix.

Comment: yeah exactly, so can you show that $K + I$ is PSD? Because that means that $k' = k + \delta$ is PSD as that's the corresponding kernel matrix

Comment: Yeah, how can I show that? That's where I have issues

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $x \in \mathbb R^n$ and let $K_{ij} = k(x_i, x_j)$, $\Delta_{ij} = \delta(x_i, x_j)$. Then for any non-zero $y \in \mathbb R^n$ we have
$$
y^T (K + \Delta)y = \underbrace{y^T K y}_{\geq 0} + y^T\Delta y
$$
so we need to look at $y^T \Delta y \stackrel ?{\geq} 0$ in order to decide if $k'$ is PSD.

For $y^T \Delta y$ we have
$$
y^T \Delta y = \sum_{ij} y_iy_j\delta_{ij} = \sum_i y_i^2 \delta_{ii} = y^T y > 0
$$
since $y\neq 0$. We could have also just noted that $\Delta = I$ so $y^T \Delta y = y^T I y = y^T y > 0$.

This means that $K + \Delta$ is PD, not even just PSD, and so $k'$ is too. Intuitively, PD matrices are ones that are diagonally dominant and we've just added $1$ to the diagonal of $K$. We can also think of this as adding $1$ to each eigenvalue of $K$, which again guarantees invertibility as it is already PSD so now all eigenvalues are bounded away from $0$.

Finally, if $K = X^TX$ (i.e. we're using the linear kernel) then $K + \Delta$ is exactly a ridge regression with $\lambda = 1$. We just proved a special case of the result that $X^TX + \lambda I$ is always invertible for $\lambda > 0$.

Answer (score 1):

@Chaconne proof is better than mine as it give more details. But if you want to use results about kernels to avoid all the calculations, you can use the following results.

**The limit of a sequence of kernels is a kernel**

*If $\kappa_1, \kappa_2, \dots$ are kernels, and $\kappa(x, y) := \lim_{n \to \infty} \kappa_n(x, y)$ exists for all $x, y$, then $\kappa$ is a kernel.*

**The sum of two kernels is a kernel**

*If $\kappa_1$ and $\kappa_2$ are kernels, so is $\kappa_1 + \kappa_2$.*

Now, note that $\delta = \lim_{\sigma\rightarrow \infty} (x,y\rightarrow \exp(-\frac{||x-y||^2)}{2\sigma^2}))$, the pointwise limit of the gaussian kernel. So $\delta+\kappa$ is a kernel, as a sum of two kernels.